# Understanding the density matrix for systems in thermal equilibrium

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, density-operator, trace

If the eigenstate $| i\rangle$ of the Hamiltonian $\hat H$ has energy $E_i$ the relative probability of the system being in that state is $e^{-\beta E_i}$ where $\beta = 1/\left(k_BT\right)$.

The density matrix is then:

$$\hat{\rho} =  \frac{1}{Z} \sum_i e^{- \beta E_i} | i \rangle \langle i| = \frac{e^{-\beta \hat H}}{Z}   \tag{1}$$

where

$$ Z = \sum_i e^{- \beta E_i} = \mathrm{Tr}(e^{- \beta \hat H}) . \tag{2}$$

I can easily prove to myself the validity of (2) however I am unsure about (1), namely why it is that:

$$\sum_i e^{- \beta E_i} | i \rangle \langle i| = e^{-\beta \hat H}$$

Comment: Equation one is the eigendecomposition of the function of operators $e^{\beta \hat{H}}$. It’s important to note that the $H$ on the right hand side of your equation is an operator and not a function of c-numbers. It follows from the spectral theorem essentially https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's easiest to work backwards. Let the right hand side of the equation act on an arbitrary vector $|A\rangle$.
$$e^{-\beta \hat H}|A\rangle$$
Next, let's label the eigenvectors of the operator $\hat H$ with an index $i$ so that
$$\hat H|i\rangle = E_i|i\rangle .$$
This also implies that $$e^{-\beta\hat H}|i\rangle = e^{-\beta E_i}|i\rangle .$$
These eigenvectors form a complete basis so we can write
$$|A\rangle = \sum_i |i\rangle \langle i|A\rangle .$$
Now we have
$$e^{-\beta \hat H}|A\rangle = \sum_i e^{-\beta \hat H}|i\rangle \langle i|A\rangle = \sum_i e^{-\beta E_i}|i\rangle \langle i|A\rangle . $$
But $|A\rangle$ was arbitrary so we have the result you wanted as a general matrix identity.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to justify that is to evaluate the elements of $\hat{\rho}$. Then

$$
\langle j|\left(\sum_{i} e^{-\beta E_{i}}|i\rangle\langle i|\right)|m\rangle=\langle j|e^{-\beta H}|m\rangle
$$
which, by using the fact that $|i\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$ (the basis generated by the eigenstates of $\hat{H}$ can always be chosen to be an orthonormal basis) implies that
$$
\sum_{i} e^{-\beta E_{i}}\delta_{ji}\delta_{im}=e^{-\beta E_m}\delta_{jm},
$$
where in the left-hand side we used the fact that a function of an operator evaluated at an eigenstate, is the function evaluated at the corresponding eigenvalue times the eigenstate (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function). By summing over $i$ (it needs to be at least equal to $j$) we obtain
$$
 e^{-\beta E_{j}}\delta_{jm}=e^{-\beta E_j}\delta_{jm},
$$
indicating that all elements of both operators are the same, hence they are equal.